# Looking to create a Hemispherical model - STL

Tags: stl-format

Here's the goal: print a 3d model hemisphere with 50 equidistant holes for a LED lamp (12mm bullet-style Neopixels), so each hole being 12mm in diameter, and spaced 42mm apart.

I've found https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpherePoints.html to determine the points, and came across https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/170443 which looks like it would create the 3D hemisphere shell nicely.

However, I'm a complete noob regards Mathematica/Wolfram, so don't know how to merge those two, let alone create the points as 12mm holes, with the 42mm spacing.  I suspect I could work through it but would need a month or three to get to a possible result.  I'm hoping an expert can point me in the direction of the relevant parts:

- how to overlay the spherepoints function on the hemisphere shell;
- set the diameter of the spherepoints to 12mm;
- expand the shell so that spherepoints are at least 42mm equidistant.  This part is optional: not sure if the lamp would look better with the Neopixel bullets close together, or spaced out and covered with ping pong balls (40mm dia.);
- save the resulting model as a STL file for printing.

(In a perfect work I'd do this in OpenSCAD but don't think scad could to the spherepoints function)

Thanks,
G.

Comment: What is the geometry of a hole? Is it a cylinder that "drills" down to the center of the sphere? Where do the wires to the leds go?

Comment: Thinking ahead, if this ends up requiring Region arithmetic in Mathematica, you may be better off using Mathematica to generate the data which you import to OpenSCAD for STL generation. OpenSCAD does a much better job a creating clean and correct STL data. So, we might let Mathematica generate the 50 sphere points, output that data in a format appropriate for OpenSCAD, and then do the rest of the geometry and STL generation in OpenSCAD.

Comment: Geometry of the hole does point down towards the centre of the sphere but given the shell only needs to be 1-2mm thick, the angle shouldn't be an issue. Happy to look at Mathematica+SCAD if that is a workable path!

Comment: oh, i see. If I were doing it, I'd definitely use OpenSCAD for everything except generating the sphere centers for the holes. Once you have the sphere centers in Mathematica, turn the list into a string, then do a string replace to turn the curly braces into square braces. Export that data and import it into OpenSCAD. Use those points as centers of spheres (there is a for loop in OpenSCAD, but I don't remember syntax right now). Use those spheres as cutouts applied to your shell (the main shell should be easy to do in OpenSCAD). I think the curvature of the little spheres won't matter.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to remember now, maybe you can't import text data in OpenSCAD. Maybe I had to copy-paste the text into OpenSCAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach uses `SpherePoints` to generate the hole positions and then exports an OpenSCAD script containing the SCAD commands required to generate the lamp.  The `openscad` is command is executed from within *Mathematica* to produce an STL file, which is then imported and displayed vis-à-vis the generated hole positions.  The STL file can be further processed (sliced) and sent to a 3D printer.

#### Preliminary

First, define two functions to will simplify things later.  `minPositive` returns the minimum positive value from a list.  `scadForm` converts a list to a string containing square brackets instead of curly braces.

```
minPositive[x_List] := Min[Select[x, 0 < # &]]
scadForm[x_List] := StringReplace[ToString[x], {"{" -> "[",  "}" -> "]"}]
```

#### Parameters

The basic parameters that must be selected by the user are the outer diameter, the thickness of the shell, the hole diameter and the number of holes.  Two other parameters define how much of the original sphere is used and how much of the sphere has holes.

```
outer = 145 (* radius of sphere *);
thick = 5 (* thickness of hemispherical shell *);
holeDiam = 12 ;
npts0 = 50 (* approximate number of holes to generate *);

holeZmin = 0  (* minimum z-coordinate for hole centers, fraction of outer radius *);
zCutPlane = 0  (* z-coord for cutting plane, fraction of outer radius *);
```

We may not want holes near the edge of the hemisphere.  Setting `holeZmin` to zero would allow hole near the edge.  Setting `holeZmin` to 0.2, say, would eliminate any holes with a $z\leq R/5$, where R is the outer radius of the sphere.

We may want a little more or less than a hemisphere.  Setting `zCutPlane` to -0.2, say, would cut the sphere at $z=-R/5$, where $R$ is the outer radius.

Normally the code will give the specified number of holes.  But in some cases the number of remaining points may different than the number of holes we specify.  If you ask for 50 points and get only 49, then ask for 51.

#### Point generation & checking

```
pts = Select[SpherePoints[Round[2 npts0/(1 - holeZmin)]], 
   Last[#] > holeZmin &];
npts = Length[pts] (* actual number of points *)

nearest = outer*minPositive /@ DistanceMatrix[pts] // MinMax

angles = Cases[CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", pts],
   {a_, b_, c_} :> Round[{0, b, c}/Degree, 1]];
```

The user must check that the code has produced the correct number of points (holes) and minimum hole spacing is adequate.

`SpherePoints` generates points over an entire sphere so we generate extras and throw away the ones having z-coordinate less than a certain value.  The remaining points locate the holes through the shell.  Note that `holeZMin` is used on the unit sphere, so its value must be between -1 and 1.

`nearest` indicates how close the holes are to one another.  If the hole centers are too close, we must increase the outer radius, or reduce the number of holes.  `nearest` has two values.  For any hole center, the straight line distance (not along the surface) to the closest adjacent hole is at least the first value and not greater than the second value.

`angles` specifies the orientation of the holes in spherical polar coordinates.  The first coordinate is always zero, second coordinate is the polar angle (from the z-axis) and the third is zenith angle (from the x-axis).  These angles are degrees of arc.

#### Generate the OpenSCAD script

`sParams` is a string that contains the required parameters in SCAD-format.  This string contains user parameters and calculated angles for all of the holes.

`sCode` is a string that contains the SCAD commands.  Briefly, the code creates a solid sphere, then hollows it out, then cuts off the botton, the generates the each of the holes.

```
sParams = StringJoin[{"\n\n//\n// Created by Wolfram Mathematica ",
    ToString[$Version], "\n//\n\n",
    "outer = ", ToString[outer], "; // radius of outer surface\n",
    "thick = ", ToString[thick], "; // thickness of shell\n",
    "inner = outer - thick; // radius of inner surface\n",
    "mid = (inner + outer) / 2;\n",
    "diam = ", ToString[holeDiam], "; // diameter of holes\n",
    "radius = diam / 2;\n",
    "zcut = ", ToString[-outer*(1 - zCutPlane)], 
    "; // z-coord of bottom of \"hemisphere\"\n",
    "npts = ", ToString[Length[pts]], "; // number of holes\n",
    "alfa = ", scadForm[angles], "; // x-, y- and z-rotation angles\n",
    "\n\n"}];

sCode = StringJoin[{
    "difference() {\n",
    "  sphere(r=outer); // full solid sphere\n",
    "  sphere(r=inner); // hollow part\n",
    "  translate([0,0,zcut]) { // remove lower hemisphere\n", 
    "    cube(2*outer,center=true);}\n\n",
    "  for(i=[0:npts-1]) {  // make the holes\n",
    "    rotate(alfa[i]) translate([0,0,mid])\n", 
    "      cylinder(r=radius, h=2*thick, center=true);\n",
    "  } // end of for\n", "} // end of difference\n",
    "\n\n"}];
```

#### Generate the STL file and view the results

Finally, the SCAD code is exported to a script file, "lamp.scad".  The `openscad` command is executed to render the geometry and produce an STL model in a file named "lamp.stl".  The output of the `openscad` command is shown.  The resulting STL model is read back into *Mathematica* for visual evaluation.

The following code uses the Linux path name to the `openscad` command.  The two files were both written to the user's home directory.  Your results could be different.

```
Export["lamp.scad", StringJoin[{sParams, sCode}], "Text"];
RunProcess[{"/usr/bin/openscad", "-o", "lamp.stl", "lamp.scad"}]
stl = Import["lamp.stl"];
Show[{stl, Graphics3D@{Red, PointSize[.01], Point@(outer*pts)}}]

(*  <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
    "StandardError" -> "Geometries in cache: 56
    Geometry cache size in bytes: 275776
    CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 2
    CGAL cache size in bytes: 10097304
    Total rendering time: 0:00:10.452
       Top level object is a 3D object:
       Simple:        yes
       Vertices:     3925
       Halfedges:   12860
       Edges:        6430
       Halffacets:   4834
       Facets:       2417
       Volumes:         2
    "|>  *)
```

[image]

#### Final adjustments

In this case we see that some of the holes fell too close to the edge of the hemisphere.  If we want holes there then we should adjust `zCutPlane` to about -0.1, which will cut the sphere below the xy-plane.  Or, if we want to keep the hemisphere but move the holes away from the edge, we can adjust `holeZmin` to about 0.15.  Or, we can do both.  Note, however, that forcing the holes away from the edge will move them closer together, so check the value of `nearest`.  It is also possible to allow the holes to extend below the xy-plane, or to cut the sphere above the xy-plane.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!